# How to reload unreal development kit after script change

Tags: scripting, reload, unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

i am currently learning unreal scripting. i am creating them on visual studio then compile them in it. I have created a level with the actor i have created.

The problem i have is every time i make changes to the script I am closing the UDK and reopen the level to see the changes.

Is there a way of saying to UDK to reload?

Answer (score 2):

If you make changes to the script, you need to close any instances of UDK.exe, whether game or editor.

Here is a workflow to speed up the whole process by using .bat files to run the game or editor.

1. Create a text file and rename it to run_game.bat. Inside the file put the following text, adjusting the path to match your project settings:

*C:\UDK\Kel\Binaries\Win32\udk.exe Level01*

Note that Level01 is the name of your level / map file. This .bat file will run your **game** within that level.

Next, create another .bat file called run_editor.bat and put this text inside:

*C:\UDK\Kel\Binaries\Win32\udk.exe editor Level01*

By adding the *editor* parameter, you're asking to run the **editor** directly with the desired level.

2. Copy the two .bat files in C:\Users[Your username] for fast access.
3. Open the command line by pressing Windows + R, then typing cmd and hitting Enter. Type either run_game or run_editor and hit Enter.

If you have uncompiled code, you'll be asked whether to compile it, so say yes. You will also see any errors or warnings that showed up during compile, which is useful. If everything went well after the compile, press the Up key or type in the name of the .bat you are trying to run, and hit Enter.

Using the above method is also faster because it doesn't require you to compile the scripts in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. Changes to UnrealScript require recompiling the `.u` file, and the game/editor has to be closed so the file can be deleted and recreated.

I'm not sure from your question if you're saying you're reopening the UDK editor every time you want to see the change, or if you're just reopening the game. If you just want to modify the script, compile, and see the result (without modifying the level), you don't have to reopen the editor. You can just run UDK.exe, press the '~' key to bring up the console, and type `open yourlevelname`. Or you can create a shortcut that runs `UDK.exe yourlevelname` to start the game on that level. Of course if you want to spawn in and run around, you'll need to put a `PlayerStart` in your level.